# AFNetwoking OR UIWebview Depreciation deadline for Application Updates

Tags: ios, uiwebview, alamofire, afnetworking, wkwebview

**My Application is on App Store, That is using AFNetworking, AFNetwoking Using UIWebView**

**- Depreciation deadline**

- i am not sure Can we Continuously Update Application till 31 December
  2020, Or Just once During this time period??
- I attached screen short of email, please check.
- Actually my Security Module is written in AFNetworking, HMAC SHA256, I am Facing issue to convert in Alamofire, so that i want to know Actual deadline.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in AFNetworking 4.

Comment: Yes, the UIWebView issue has been fixed in lated AFNetworking. But facing Exceptions.. (Upvote)

App getting crashed after updating the AFNetworking

'a security policy configured with can only be applied on a manager with a secure base url (i.e. https)

  Jon Shier , @RashidAli  Can you please help us on it...
Thanks..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61525821/afnetworking-3-2-0-a-security-policy-configured-with-can-only-be-applied-on-a-m